# Entity Framework 5 dynamic select based on include

Tags: c#, linq, select, entity

I'm using EF to look up a contact and then include a company in the graph then put it in a DTO. I only want the company DTO created if it exists, I don't want to include a blank DTO if it doesn't. (It's being transferred in a REST service and I don't want countless empty tags.)

```
return (from c in _dc.Contact.Include("Company")
                where c.ContactId == id
                select new ContactDto
                {
                    ContactId = c.ContactId,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    Company = new CompanyDto
                                {
                                    CompanyId = c.Company.CompanyId,
                                    Name = c.Company.Name
                                } 
                }).ToList();
```

This crashed for contacts that have no company associated with them. Normally I would create a blank object, but this will as stated above include lots of blank tags.

I'd like to do something like (Which obviously isn't possible)

```
return (from c in _dc.Contact.Include("Company")
                where c.ContactId == id
                select new ContactDto
                {
                    ContactId = c.ContactId,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    if (c.Company !=null) 
                    {
                        Company = new CompanyDto
                                {
                                    CompanyId = c.Company.CompanyId,
                                    Name = c.Company.Name
                                } ;
                    }
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thank you in advance

Oli

Comment: Does left outer join work for you? Have you tried that?

Comment: Sorry for a slow response. I'd had not tried, I'll let you know. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try with a ternary operator:

```
            Company = (c.Company!=null)?
                (new CompanyDto
                {
                    CompanyId = c.Company.CompanyId,
                    Name = c.Company.Name
                })
                :null
```

Comment: I tried this, I believe I got an error saying that setting Contact to null was not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I don't have VS in front of me, so you need to take care of the syntax.

```
return (from c in _dc.Contact 
              join co in _dc.Company on c.CompanyId equals co.CompanyId into subCompanies
                from sc in subCompanies.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where c.ContactId == id
                select new ContactDto
                {
                    ContactId = c.ContactId,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    Company = sc
                }).FirstOrDefault()
```